# Heroku Issue When Editing Blog (Random Routing to Matchheight.js)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a very strange issue when editing a blog entry on my Heroku production site.  It works fine locally, but when I try to submit from the edit page on Heroku, it redirects back to the edit page (as the controller dictates for unsuccessful edits) with the following errors in the log:

```
2018-07-06T20:33:50.737734+00:00 app[web.1]: [d5bcfbfd-5fae-430c-bab3-2523189aa1de]   Rendering blogs/edit.html.erb within layouts/application 
2018-07-06T20:33:50.749041+00:00 app[web.1]: [d5bcfbfd-5fae-430c-bab3-2523189aa1de]   Pillar Load (2.7ms)  SELECT "pillars".* FROM "pillars" 
2018-07-06T20:33:50.754540+00:00 app[web.1]: [d5bcfbfd-5fae-430c-bab3-2523189aa1de]   Rendered blogs/_form.html.erb (16.5ms) 
2018-07-06T20:33:50.761894+00:00 app[web.1]: [d5bcfbfd-5fae-430c-bab3-2523189aa1de]   Rendered blogs/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (24.0ms) 
2018-07-06T20:33:50.767560+00:00 app[web.1]: [d5bcfbfd-5fae-430c-bab3-2523189aa1de]   User Load (2.5ms) SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]] 
2018-07-06T20:33:50.769281+00:00 app[web.1]: [d5bcfbfd-5fae-430c-bab3-2523189aa1de] Completed 200 OK in 56ms (Views: 26.8ms | ActiveRecord: 15.0ms) 
2018-07-06T20:33:50.771232+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.45.41.181 - - [06/Jul/2018:20:33:50 UTC] "POST /blogs/6-keys-to-looking-at-houses HTTP/1.1" 200 18021 
2018-07-06T20:33:50.771291+00:00 app[web.1]: http://www.linchpinrealty.com/blogs/6-keys-to-looking-at-houses -> /blogs/6-keys-to-looking-at-houses 
2018-07-06T20:33:50.954960+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.45.41.181 - - [06/Jul/2018:20:33:50 UTC] "GET /assets/application-8bd9bf2fc554870a56340f38f52088acfd66e1bb586ccddd5bf0587786e8009c.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0 
2018-07-06T20:33:50.954972+00:00 app[web.1]: http://www.linchpinrealty.com/blogs/6-keys-to-looking-at-houses -> /assets/application-8bd9bf2fc554870a56340f38f52088acfd66e1bb586ccddd5bf0587786e8009c.css 2018-07-06T20:33:50.772309+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/blogs/6-keys-to-looking-at-houses" host=www.linchpinrealty.com request_id=d5bcfbfd-5fae-430c-bab3-2523189aa1de fwd="68.225.227.137" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=154ms status=200 bytes=19033 protocol=http 
2018-07-06T20:33:50.955207+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-8bd9bf2fc554870a56340f38f52088acfd66e1bb586ccddd5bf0587786e8009c.css" host=www.linchpinrealty.com request_id=96002827-fdc6-4e95-9b07-73bc2784b07d fwd="68.225.227.137" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=11ms status=304 bytes=133 protocol=http 
2018-07-06T20:33:51.222463+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/blogs/jquery.matchHeight.js" host=www.linchpinrealty.com request_id=829b1a4f-1bb8-4aa4-952d-db79d7252381 fwd="68.225.227.137" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=17ms status=404 bytes=2271 protocol=http 
2018-07-06T20:33:51.219409+00:00 app[web.1]: [829b1a4f-1bb8-4aa4-952d-db79d7252381] Started GET "/blogs/jquery.matchHeight.js" for 68.225.227.137 at 2018-07-06 20:33:51 +0000 
2018-07-06T20:33:51.220852+00:00 app[web.1]: [829b1a4f-1bb8-4aa4-952d-db79d7252381] 2018-07-06T20:33:51.220919+00:00 app[web.1]: [829b1a4f-1bb8-4aa4-952d-db79d7252381] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/blogs/jquery.matchHeight.js"): 
2018-07-06T20:33:51.220979+00:00 app[web.1]: [829b1a4f-1bb8-4aa4-952d-db79d7252381] 2018-07-06T20:33:51.221064+00:00 app[web.1]: [829b1a4f-1bb8-4aa4-952d-db79d7252381] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:65:in `call' 
2018-07-06T20:33:51.221067+00:00 app[web.1]: [829b1a4f-1bb8-4aa4-952d-db79d7252381] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call' 
2018-07-06T20:33:51.221069+00:00 app[web.1]: [829b1a4f-1bb8-4aa4-952d-db79d7252381] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app' 
2018-07-06T20:33:51.221070+00:00 app[web.1]: [829b1a4f-1bb8-4aa4-952d-db79d7252381] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call' 
2018-07-06T20:33:51.221072+00:00 app[web.1]: [829b1a4f-1bb8-4aa4-952d-db79d7252381] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged' 
2018-07-06T20:33:51.221073+00:00 app[web.1]: [829b1a4f-1bb8-4aa4-952d-db79d7252381] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged' 
2018-07-06T20:33:51.221075+00:00 app[web.1]: [829b1a4f-1bb8-4aa4-952d-db79d7252381] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged' 
2018-07-06T20:33:51.221077+00:00 app[web.1]: [829b1a4f-1bb8-4aa4-952d-db79d7252381] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call' 2018-07-06T20:33:51.221078+00:00 app[web.1]: [829b1a4f-1bb8-4aa4-952d-db79d7252381] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call' 
2018-07-06T20:33:51.221080+00:00 app[web.1]: [829b1a4f-1bb8-4aa4-952d-db79d7252381] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call' 
2018-07-06T20:33:51.221081+00:00 app[web.1]: [829b1a4f-1bb8-4aa4-952d-db79d7252381] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call' 
2018-07-06T20:33:51.221083+00:00 app[web.1]: [829b1a4f-1bb8-4aa4-952d-db79d7252381] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call' 
2018-07-06T20:33:51.221085+00:00 app[web.1]: [829b1a4f-1bb8-4aa4-952d-db79d7252381] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call' 
2018-07-06T20:33:51.221086+00:00 app[web.1]: [829b1a4f-1bb8-4aa4-952d-db79d7252381] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call' 2018-07-06T20:33:51.221088+00:00 app[web.1]: [829b1a4f-1bb8-4aa4-952d-db79d7252381] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call' 
2018-07-06T20:33:51.221090+00:00 app[web.1]: [829b1a4f-1bb8-4aa4-952d-db79d7252381] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call' 2018-07-06T20:33:51.221091+00:00 app[web.1]: [829b1a4f-1bb8-4aa4-952d-db79d7252381] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call' 
2018-07-06T20:33:51.221093+00:00 app[web.1]: [829b1a4f-1bb8-4aa4-952d-db79d7252381] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:86:in `service' 
2018-07-06T20:33:51.221094+00:00 app[web.1]: [829b1a4f-1bb8-4aa4-952d-db79d7252381] vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:140:in `service' 2018-07-06T20:33:51.221096+00:00 app[web.1]: [829b1a4f-1bb8-4aa4-952d-db79d7252381] vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:96:in `run' 2018-07-06T20:33:51.221097+00:00 app[web.1]: [829b1a4f-1bb8-4aa4-952d-db79d7252381] vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/server.rb:296:in `block in start_thread' 
2018-07-06T20:33:51.222165+00:00 app[web.1]:
    10.45.41.181 - - [06/Jul/2018:20:33:51 UTC] "GET /blogs/jquery.matchHeight.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2006 
2018-07-06T20:33:51.222224+00:00 app[web.1]: http://www.linchpinrealty.com/blogs/6-keys-to-looking-at-houses -> /blogs/jquery.matchHeight.js 
2018-07-06T20:34:00.039382+00:00 heroku[run.7407]: Process exited with status 0 
2018-07-06T20:34:00.077058+00:00 heroku[run.7407]: State changed from up to complete
```

I do use `matchHeight.js` in the app, but not on the `blogs#edit` or `blogs#show` page, so this is weird.

Finally, I did just update to Rails 5.2, so this could (but hopefully doesn't) have to do with that.

Can anyone see what's going wrong here?  It **still** has an issue when I try update fields in `rails c`!

**UPDATE**

As requested, here's what happens when I run `heroku logs -t`:

```
2018-07-07T02:04:30.529049+00:00 app[web.1]: [198bc7e3-94bd-497c-acfd-6766dc07b44d]   Rendered blogs/_form.html.erb (11.4ms)
2018-07-07T02:04:30.529526+00:00 app[web.1]: [198bc7e3-94bd-497c-acfd-6766dc07b44d]   Rendered blogs/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (12.0ms)
2018-07-07T02:04:30.533211+00:00 app[web.1]: [198bc7e3-94bd-497c-acfd-6766dc07b44d]   User Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2018-07-07T02:04:30.534396+00:00 app[web.1]: [198bc7e3-94bd-497c-acfd-6766dc07b44d] Completed 200 OK in 35ms (Views: 14.6ms | ActiveRecord: 9.2ms)
2018-07-07T02:04:30.535830+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.7.158.42 - - [07/Jul/2018:02:04:30 UTC] "POST /blogs/6-keys-to-looking-at-houses HTTP/1.1" 200 18071
2018-07-07T02:04:30.535871+00:00 app[web.1]: http://www.linchpinrealty.com/blogs/6-keys-to-looking-at-houses/edit -> /blogs/6-keys-to-looking-at-houses
2018-07-07T02:04:30.537104+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/blogs/6-keys-to-looking-at-houses" host=www.linchpinrealty.com request_id=198bc7e3-94bd-497c-acfd-6766dc07b44d fwd="68.225.227.137" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=134ms status=200 bytes=19083 protocol=http
2018-07-07T02:04:30.950397+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/blogs/jquery.matchHeight.js" host=www.linchpinrealty.com request_id=3d1460f7-b943-4628-a2be-fc0fd11b717c fwd="68.225.227.137" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=404 bytes=2271 protocol=http
2018-07-07T02:04:30.947883+00:00 app[web.1]: [3d1460f7-b943-4628-a2be-fc0fd11b717c] Started GET "/blogs/jquery.matchHeight.js" for 68.225.227.137 at 2018-07-07 02:04:30 +0000
2018-07-07T02:04:30.948912+00:00 app[web.1]: [3d1460f7-b943-4628-a2be-fc0fd11b717c]
2018-07-07T02:04:30.948946+00:00 app[web.1]: [3d1460f7-b943-4628-a2be-fc0fd11b717c] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/blogs/jquery.matchHeight.js"):
2018-07-07T02:04:30.949095+00:00 app[web.1]: [3d1460f7-b943-4628-a2be-fc0fd11b717c]
2018-07-07T02:04:30.949104+00:00 app[web.1]: [3d1460f7-b943-4628-a2be-fc0fd11b717c] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:65:in `call'
2018-07-07T02:04:30.949106+00:00 app[web.1]: [3d1460f7-b943-4628-a2be-fc0fd11b717c] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
2018-07-07T02:04:30.949108+00:00 app[web.1]: [3d1460f7-b943-4628-a2be-fc0fd11b717c] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2018-07-07T02:04:30.949110+00:00 app[web.1]: [3d1460f7-b943-4628-a2be-fc0fd11b717c] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
2018-07-07T02:04:30.949112+00:00 app[web.1]: [3d1460f7-b943-4628-a2be-fc0fd11b717c] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
2018-07-07T02:04:30.949113+00:00 app[web.1]: [3d1460f7-b943-4628-a2be-fc0fd11b717c] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
2018-07-07T02:04:30.949115+00:00 app[web.1]: [3d1460f7-b943-4628-a2be-fc0fd11b717c] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
2018-07-07T02:04:30.949116+00:00 app[web.1]: [3d1460f7-b943-4628-a2be-fc0fd11b717c] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
2018-07-07T02:04:30.949118+00:00 app[web.1]: [3d1460f7-b943-4628-a2be-fc0fd11b717c] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
2018-07-07T02:04:30.949120+00:00 app[web.1]: [3d1460f7-b943-4628-a2be-fc0fd11b717c] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
2018-07-07T02:04:30.949122+00:00 app[web.1]: [3d1460f7-b943-4628-a2be-fc0fd11b717c] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
2018-07-07T02:04:30.949124+00:00 app[web.1]: [3d1460f7-b943-4628-a2be-fc0fd11b717c] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
2018-07-07T02:04:30.949126+00:00 app[web.1]: [3d1460f7-b943-4628-a2be-fc0fd11b717c] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
2018-07-07T02:04:30.949128+00:00 app[web.1]: [3d1460f7-b943-4628-a2be-fc0fd11b717c] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
2018-07-07T02:04:30.949130+00:00 app[web.1]: [3d1460f7-b943-4628-a2be-fc0fd11b717c] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'
2018-07-07T02:04:30.949132+00:00 app[web.1]: [3d1460f7-b943-4628-a2be-fc0fd11b717c] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
2018-07-07T02:04:30.949133+00:00 app[web.1]: [3d1460f7-b943-4628-a2be-fc0fd11b717c] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
2018-07-07T02:04:30.949135+00:00 app[web.1]: [3d1460f7-b943-4628-a2be-fc0fd11b717c] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:86:in `service'
2018-07-07T02:04:30.949137+00:00 app[web.1]: [3d1460f7-b943-4628-a2be-fc0fd11b717c] vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:140:in `service'
2018-07-07T02:04:30.949138+00:00 app[web.1]: [3d1460f7-b943-4628-a2be-fc0fd11b717c] vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:96:in `run'
2018-07-07T02:04:30.949140+00:00 app[web.1]: [3d1460f7-b943-4628-a2be-fc0fd11b717c] vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/server.rb:296:in `block in start_thread'
2018-07-07T02:04:30.949901+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.7.158.42 - - [07/Jul/2018:02:04:30 UTC] "GET /blogs/jquery.matchHeight.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2006
2018-07-07T02:04:30.949948+00:00 app[web.1]: http://www.linchpinrealty.com/blogs/6-keys-to-looking-at-houses -> /blogs/jquery.matchHeight.js
2018-07-07T02:04:46.808672+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path="/" host=www.linchpinrealty.com request_id=d2839548-a8c9-402f-985d-7698f49f6bb0 fwd="63.143.42.245" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=22ms status=200 bytes=896 protocol=http
2018-07-07T02:04:46.792120+00:00 app[web.1]: [d2839548-a8c9-402f-985d-7698f49f6bb0] Started HEAD "/" for 63.143.42.245 at 2018-07-07 02:04:46 +0000
2018-07-07T02:04:46.793174+00:00 app[web.1]: [d2839548-a8c9-402f-985d-7698f49f6bb0] Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
2018-07-07T02:04:46.794570+00:00 app[web.1]: [d2839548-a8c9-402f-985d-7698f49f6bb0]   Rendering home/index.html.erb within layouts/application
2018-07-07T02:04:46.799976+00:00 app[web.1]: [d2839548-a8c9-402f-985d-7698f49f6bb0]   Blog Load (2.5ms)  SELECT  "blogs".* FROM "blogs" ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 5]]
2018-07-07T02:04:46.804154+00:00 app[web.1]: [d2839548-a8c9-402f-985d-7698f49f6bb0]   Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (9.4ms)
2018-07-07T02:04:46.808050+00:00 app[web.1]: [d2839548-a8c9-402f-985d-7698f49f6bb0] Completed 200 OK in 15ms (Views: 11.3ms | ActiveRecord: 2.5ms)
2018-07-07T02:04:46.809651+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.93.165.91 - - [07/Jul/2018:02:04:46 UTC] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 0
2018-07-07T02:04:46.809685+00:00 app[web.1]: http://www.linchpinrealty.com -> /
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I do a have a conscious (somewhat)

For anyone else that encounters this issue...

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51219549/rails-issue-blogs-count-shows-up-locally-but-not-on-heroku/51220134#51220134) answer!

Answer (score 0):

What do you get when you type heroku logs -t?