# Rails Issue: @blogs.count shows up locally but not on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

On my app I have models for `Pillar` and `Blog`.  Each `blog` `belongs_to` a `pillar`.  I have the following logic in my `pillars#show` so that I can display the blogs belonging to a certain pillar on that pillar's `show` page:

```
  def show
    @blogs = Blog.where(pillars_id: @pillar.id).limit(6)
  end
```

Then, on the `show.html.erb` page, I have this:

```
<% if @blogs.count != 0 %>
  <div class="row blue-stripe">
    <div class="container">
      <h2 class="text-center">Blogs about <%= @pillar.name %></h2>
      <% @blogs.each do |blog| %>
        <%= link_to blog_path(blog) do %>
          <div class="card blog-card col-xs-6 col-md-3">
              <%= image_tag blog.image.url, alt: blog.title %>
              <h3><%= blog.title %></h3>
              <p><%= blog.teaser %></p>
              <p><em><%= link_to "Read More", blog_path(blog) %>...</em></p>
          </div> <!-- card -->
        <% end %> <!-- link -->
      <% end %> <!-- blogs each -->
    </div> <!-- container -->
  </div> <!-- row -->
<% end %>
```

This works perfectly locally, but when I deploy to Heroku the whole section doesn't show up.

As an example, I confirmed by running `heroku run rails c` that there are, in fact, blogs belonging to the pillar I'm examining.  For example, one blog's record looks like this:

> Blog Load (2.9ms)  SELECT  "blogs".* FROM "blogs" ORDER BY
>   "blogs"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
>   => #Touring a
>   house is kind of like going on a firs...", user_id: 2, created_at:
>   "2018-06-03 21:00:56", updated_at: "2018-06-03 21:00:56",
>   image_file_name: "53600574_l_(Cropped).jpeg", image_content_type:
>   "image/jpeg", image_file_size: 569841, image_updated_at: "2018-06-03
>   21:00:56", slug: "6-keys-to-looking-at-houses", link_text: "Download a
>   Printable Sheet for Home Tour Notes", link_filename:
>   "app/assets/images/house_tour_notes.pdf", pillars_id: 3>

Yet when I go to `pillars/3` the blue stripe for the blogs (the interior of `if @blogs.count`) doesn't appear.

Can anyone figure out what's happening between `localhost` and Heroku to make this glitch?

Comment: you can `heroku run rails c` to access your app's heroku console and check if your table has data or not

Comment: @sa77, the question shows that has already been verified. Is there anything in your heroku log when you make that request that could point you in the right direction?

Comment: @MarkMerritt right .. sorry about that

Comment: @sa77 The console actually DOES NOT save data either.  I originally thought it did, but when I exited out of the console and came back in it hadn't been saved to the database.

Comment: Don't know what's happening but you can try different way like `if @blogs.present?` instead of `@blogs.count != 0`

Comment: You noted that each Blog belongs_to a Pillar. Did you make sure to add `has_many :pillars` (or `has_one :pillar`, depending on your needs) in the Blog model? I could see a situation where you explicitly set the relationship in development (via seeds or some other way), which would not work in production.

Comment: Ahhhhh@  @MarkMerritt that was it!  I had `belongs_to` but `has_one` works!  Write up the answer and I will happily select it!  Thank you!

Comment: Good stuff @Liz. Glad it worked! Posted as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You noted that each Blog belongs_to a Pillar. Did you make sure to add `has_many :pillars` (or `has_one :pillar`, depending on your needs) in the Blog model? I could see a situation where you explicitly set the relationship in development (via seeds or some other way), which would not work in production.

Comment: If you want to repost the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51217357/heroku-issue-when-editing-blog-random-routing-to-matchheight-js), it turns out this solved another problem I was having as well.

Comment: I feel like I'm abusing the system. I'll post it there as well...I have no conscious! haha!

Comment: Eh, not your fault the answer solved both open problems.  :)